# Ruby interpreters, method execution

Tags: ruby, jruby, rubinius

I'm doing some research into how different Ruby interpreters do method execution (e.g. when you call a method in ruby, what steps does the interpreter take to find and execute it, and which structures are involved in this). I am trying to compare the performance of the different approaches being used.

The interpreters I'm looking into are: MRI, YARV, JRuby, Rubinius, Ruby EE

I am looking for any general pointers about which files in the interpreter source I should check out, and any other general information about this topic that you guys can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: note to self: YARV/MRI: rb_method_call/rb_funcall